# Extracting and parsing using python

Tags: python, parsing

I have these two lines in the format

```
VP VB go
NP PRP$ your NN left
```

saved in a text file.
I want to access this text file and then print this following result in a new text file

```
NP NN left
```

Help me how to this using python.

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: On what basis are we suppose to select `NP NN left` from the text file? Without such an explanation, `print('NP NN left')` is a valid solution.

Comment: @unutbu I want to print this for all those pattern which have NP in the beginning of the line and NN before a word in that same line.

Answer (score 1):

If I am interpreting you correctly, you want all cases of

```
NP NN word
```

in which case you could use a regex expression that looks for NP, NN, and the subsequent word:

```
import re
f = open('file.txt')
regex = r'^(NP).*?(NN) (\w+).*?$'
for line in f:
    try: ' '.join(re.search(regex, line).groups())
    except AttributeError: pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: is this better?

```
f=open("myfile")
#read all lines of the file and remove newline characters
a=[i.strip() for i in f.readlines()]
f.close()

for i in a:
  i=i.split()
  n=-1
  try:
    n=i.index("NN")
  except:
    pass
  if n!=-1 and n!=len(i)-1 and i[0]=="NP":
    print i[0], i[n], i[n+1]
```

Comment: the file have 1000 lines of those types and the number of words between NP and NN is not fixed so printing using array by giving index and specifying that a in first line won't be that possible